# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name_dropdwn' of undefined userClicked @ Code.gs:23

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was trying to enter entry through submit button and send the data into spreadsheet accordingly. However the submit button did not attempt anything as the error in **userClicked** function in **code.gs** shows *TypeError: Cannot read property 'name_dropdwn' of undefined.* The **Name** field is populated from spreadsheet, in which the **Email** field is matched from the data in the spreadsheet and auto populate the field answer.  I was following this [tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lc8-vJ5r3e0&list=PLv9Pf9aNgemt82hBENyneRyHnD-zORB3l&index=5&ab_channel=LearnGoogleSpreadsheets) but I get the error. Anyone knows how to solve it?

**page.html**

```
<div class="inner-card"><!--start row-->
      <label>Name</label>
       <select class="browser-default" id="name_dropdwn" onchange="getAutofill()" type="text" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select your name</option>
          <?!= list; ?>
       </select>
    </div><!--end row-->
    <div class="inner-card"><!--start row-->
    <label>Your Email: </label>
      <input disabled id="autofill_email" type="text" class="validate">
    </div><!--end row-->
```

**js.html**

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);
document.getElementById("name_dropdwn").addEventListener("input", getAutofill);

function doStuff(){
  var userInfo = {};
  userInfo.name_dropdwn = document.getElementById("name_dropdwn").value;
  userInfo.autofill_email = document.getElementById("autofill_email").value;

  google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
 
  document.getElementById("autofill_email").value=" ";
  M.updateTextFields();
  var myApp = document.getElementById("name_dropdwn");
  myApp.selectedIndex = 0;
  M.FormSelect.init(myApp);
}

function getAutofill(){
    var nameCode = document.getElementById("name_dropdwn").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateAutofill).getPopulate(nameCode);  
}

function updateAutofill(theEmail){
  document.getElementById("autofill_email").value = theEmail;
  M.updateTextFields();
}
```

**code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);//open URL of spreadsheet
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Populate");
  var list = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();//(row, col, no. of rows, no. of column)
  var htmlListArray = list.map(function(r){return '<option>' + r[0] + '</option>';}).join('');
  Logger.log(htmlListArray);
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");//running the <?= include ?> pieces in page.html file
  tmp.list = htmlListArray;//create variable list to pass in page.html
  return tmp.evaluate();
}
//submitted
function userClicked(userInfo){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
//[an array of column(s)]
 ws.appendRow([new Date(),userInfo.name_dropdwn, userInfo.autofill_email ]);
}
//include js and css files into page.html
function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
//populate name list fxn
function getPopulate(nameCode){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName('Populate');
  var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 7).getValues();
  var nameList = data.map(function(r){return r[0];});
  var emailList = data.map(function(r){return r[1];});
  var position = nameList.indexOf(nameCode);
  if (position > -1) {
    return emailList[position];
  }
   else { 
     return 'unavailable';
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I have managed to solve it by adding console.log on the js.html and found out that it returns null on the userInfo values because I did not include my javascript file into my html file. I have managed to solve it by adding  into the tag of my html file, in which js.html is my javascript file. Thank you all!
also thank you @nenad and @kessy for your help!

Comment: Can you check with console.log how is the field being populated as mentioned on the answer and see if it is actually correct?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I have managed to solve it after finding out the problem via console.log. it returns null because I forgot to include my javascript in the html. thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that `userInfo` is `undefined` in the `userClicked` function. Try to `console.log` the data before passing it to the function.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I have managed to solve it after finding out the problem via console.log. it returns null because I forgot to include my javascript in the html. thank you for helping!

Comment: Welcome. Consider also to upvote my answer if it helped you.